# Regex for bundleId with optional wildcard char (*) at the end

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm trying to validate an input value for bundleId. The valid value for bundleId it must be alphanumeric with (.) separated value. If we are trying to add more than one (.) in bundleId then we can have a wildcard `*` character at its last. Eg of some correct bundle id with `*` at the end. `comm.*` `comm.myapp.*` `comm.myapp.myappteam.*` are valid. But including the `*` with string will not be valid. Eg: `comm.myap*` is invalid.
Use of hyphen (-) character is also valid but in the middle of string.
Eg: `comm.myapp-team`, `comm.m-app.*`, `co.team.te-app.*`  are some valid string for bundleId.

I'm trying to validate with this regex : `@"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9])|\\*"`

```
string pattern = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9])";
            string input = "comm.app-team.*";
            Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (m.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("valid bundleId");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid bundleId");
```

I wanted this `input = "comm.app.*"` to be a valid bundle identifier.

Comment: Tested your code and i'm getting as output `valid bundleId`

Comment: Please read the problem description. Also check for example comm.app-test.test* should be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the first part with the dot as a separator and an optional hyphen.

Add an optional part that starts with the dot and matches 1+ times what is listed in the character class `\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+` and again the optional hyphen part.

At the end add matching optional `.*`

You might use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)*\*|[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.` Match chars a-z or digits and repeat 0+ times a hyphened part followed by a dot
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)*\*` Repeat the previous pattern 0+ times ending with `*`
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Repeat chars a-z or digits with hyphenated parts 0+ times
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vxUrfR/1)

Comment: @MohammadIrshad do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/tqXuOS/1 `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)*(?:\.\*)?$`

Comment: Nearly correct. But it is valid for individual string also without any period character (.) .Eg: comm is also showing correct bundle Id. But it should contains atleast one (.)

Comment: @MohammadIrshad Now it does not match a  string without a period. https://regex101.com/r/vxUrfR/1